# MySQL insert from temporary with group by

Tags: mysql

I am trying to take unique mls rows from the temporary table and throw them into the main table but the GROUP BY is giving me issues. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
INSERT into data (showing, price, mls, street, unit, showing_start, showing_end, agent, broker, telephone) SELECT showing, price, mls, street, unit, showing_start, showing_end, agent, broker, telephone from tmpdata where mls not in (SELECT mls from data) GROUP BY mls
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the GROUP BY clause to produce a set of data such that every row has a unique MLS? If MLS must be a unique ID, you need to aggregate all the other fields.

Example:
INSERT .... SELECT MAX( showing ), MAX( price ), mls, MAX( street ) ... etc.